# How to Code for Hours Slept Using R

Tags: r, variables, time

Greetings people who know R better than I do.  For a class I am working with the add health dataset.  There are 3 questions repeated twice that involve sleep patterns (what hour did you go to be, is that AM or PM, What minuet--these 3 questions are then repeated for what time someone wakes up).  Using these code snippets I have created the 2 variables on a 24 hour clock

```
data$H4SP2T[data$H4SP2T %in% c(6, 8)] <- NA
data$H4SP2M[data$H4SP2M %in% c(96, 98)] <- NA
data$H4SP2H[data$H4SP2H %in% c(96, 98)] <- NA
data$ampm2 <- car::recode(data$H4SP2T, "1=0; 2=12")
data$ampm2[data$H4SP2H==12 & data$H4SP2T==2]<-0
data$sleep <- data$H4SP2H + data$ampm2 + data$H4SP2M/60


data$H4SP1T[data$H4SP1T %in% c(6, 8)] <- NA
data$H4SP1M[data$H4SP1M %in% c(96, 98)] <- NA
data$H4SP1H[data$H4SP1H %in% c(96, 98)] <- NA
data$ampm <- car::recode(data$H4SP1T, "1=0; 2=12")
data$ampm[data$H4SP1H==12 & data$H4SP1T==2]<-0
data$wakeup <- data$H4SP1H + data$ampm + data$H4SP1M/60

summary(data$sleep)
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
1.00   12.00   22.00   17.44   23.00  107.63    1390  

summary(data$wakeup)
  Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
  1.000   5.750   6.500   7.023   7.500  23.500    1404
```

I am running into a few snags however, and am looking for how best to proceed.  The first big issue I am having is trying to figure out how to mash these together to get a 3rd variable that simple tells me how many hours someone sleeps, simply adding or subtracting them will not work because of the cyclic nature of time.  The smaller issue I was having also comes from times cyclic nature throwing off the median time when people go to bed (slightly messing with wake up time but not as much - someone going to bed after 2400 much more common that someone waking up at 0100), because someone who goes to bed at 0100 is has gone to bed 1 hour later than someone who went to bed at 2400, not 23 hours earlier.

Comment: we kinda need `data` (i.e. paste output of `dput(data)`.  `data` is also not a great variable name even though R is gd at figuring things out. it'll come back to bite you someday.

Comment: Including a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in your question will increase your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: This works much easier if you have a date and the time. Then you can combine them to do the actual calculation.

Answer (score 0):

To solve both of your issues you need to have create a starting time for reference and then have all of your time values be derived as x amount of hours after the start time.

Since i cant see the data I cant tell you exactly how to do it but there are 2 general solutions. First (and the most recommended) is to store them using [`as.POSIXlt`](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/dates.html) with wake times being the day after sleep times.

Second is you can add 24 to all your wake times. (and then while printing a simple `if(wakeup > 24){wakeup <- wakeup - 24}` to undo said change.

**Note:** Since your 3 questions dont explicitly check, you will need to make some assumptions and conditions for whether the subject went to sleep/woke up on the first or second day.